# PHP controlled MySQL database for C# applications

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I am trying to make a C# application that connects to a MySQL database through PHP. My PHP code is the following:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['number']))
{
    //Get the POST variables
    $mName = $_GET['name'];
    $mNumber = $_GET['number'];

    //Insert new contact into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `products`(`name`) VALUES (\"" . $mName . "\")";

    echo $sql;

    //Execute query
    $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
    if (!$stmt)
    {   
        echo 'Query Failed';     
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Query Successful";
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In my C# application I use a WebClient and the method DownloadString to make a request.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://manoest.dk/UpdateValue.php?name=John&number=23");

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
//client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");


var streng = client.DownloadString(uri);
```

I have tried many different things, but everytime I will get an 406 error (Not acceptable). I guess that the headers are the problem, but I have tried and can't see the problem.

Comment: If server can't answer on your "Accept" format - it answer 406. You need to check header "Accept"

Comment: Thank you, I found out that, but how do I know which Accept header to use. When requesting from my C# application, I have tried a-lot of different accept headers, but without luck.

Comment: Also you need to remove "Content-Type", because it answer header

Comment: Again thank you. I tried to remove Content-Type, but still no luck. I don't know which accept header to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `header` call in the PHP file to indicate what content-type you're producing. For example, for simple text:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Add this call before producing any output to avoid problems. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Then, add the same content-type in your C# client as your `Accept` header.

Comment: Thank you. I have now tried that, but still without any better results. I still get the "not acceptable" error, even when the header('Content-Type: text/plain'); is added, and "text/plain" is added to the accept header in the webclient.