# PHP MySQL server for C# application (406 not acceptable)

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I am trying to setup a PHP site to handle the connection to a MySQl database for a C# application. But I can't get the communication between the C# application and the PHP site to work. I always get an "406 Not acceptable" error.

Here is the code from PHP.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo "test";
?>
```

Here is the C# part.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://manoest.dk/UpdateValue.php");
request.Accept = "text/plain";
var test = request.GetResponse();

//WebClient client = new WebClient();
//client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");           
//string test = client.DownloadString("http://manoest.dk/UpdateValue.php");
```

I am pretty experienced in C#, but completely new to PHP. Hope that you can help me out.

Comment: use a web browser to request from your php script. open its "F12" tool and open the headers section. what is reported as the actual Content-Type?

Comment: I tried using postman to test that, and it says that the Content-Type is text/plain.

Comment: I just checked in C# where the response from the web request says that the Content-Type is "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions; this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431687/php-controlled-mysql-database-for-c-sharp-applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP controlled MySQL database for C# applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431687/php-controlled-mysql-database-for-c-sharp-applications)